# MySql Is it absolutely necessary to use table aliases with column names when using joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I was selecting data from two tables using inner join, and noticed that things were working fine even when I did not specify table aliases next to column names.

Is it ok to do this, or are table aliases next to column names absolutely necessary.

**Example:**

**Table One**

```
"postTitle"     "postBody"      "userId"    "userName"
"Post One"      "Body One"      "1"         "norman"
"Post Two"      "Body Two"      "1"         "norman"
"Post Three"    "Body Three"    "2"         "john"
"Post Four"     "Body Four"     "3"         "tom"
```

**Table Two**

```
"userPosts" "userFriends"   "userStatus"    "userId"    "userName"
"2"         "5"             "1"             "1"         "norman"
"1"         "2"             "0"             "2"         "john"
"1"         "3"             "0"             "3"         "tom"
```

**What I accidentally did, but still works (Note: no aliases next to columns names)**

`select postTitle, postBody, userPosts, userFriends from one a inner join two b on a.userId = b.userId where userStatus = 1;`

**What I should have done (Note: Aliases next to column names)**

`select a.postTitle, a.postBody, b.userPosts, b.userFriends from one a inner join two b on a.userId = b.userId where b.userStatus = 1;`

The first sql works perfect without using table aliases with column names. Is this a bug, or is this normal behavior. Can I be using column names without table name aliases?

I'm wondering how it's worked. In the past, it's always returned some kind of error like `column is unambiguous`

Comment: If the selected column names are unique across the joined tables then there's no ambiguity so you don't need the tablenames. If not, then you need to tell MySQL which to use. I'd argue that it's good practice to be explicit about where the data is coming from, though

Comment: If you are joining on more than one table, and doesn't know which column you're trying to retrieve so use an alias for the column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is compulsory to use table aliases in select query **only when same field names are in both tables**. If you have fields in both tables with the same field name, you will get the error:

```
column is unambiguous
```

If the fields are unique among the tables joined, there will be no ambiguity.

Comment: only if you reference the column, and you only *need* to alias *one* of the tables